# Retrieve data of customers who have more than 1 contact number and contact type as office

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to return customer id and count of customer id who have contact type "Office" and have more than 1 contact number...

Table has
(cust_id,
cust_phone,
contact_type,
cust_city,
....)

I want my output like this

| cust_id | count(cust_id) |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 |
| 1009 | 3 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1001 "ID", '++44925555876' "PHONE", 'Office' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 1001 "ID", '++44925555877' "PHONE", 'Home' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 1002 "ID", '++44925555888' "PHONE", 'Home' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 1003 "ID", '++44925555899' "PHONE", 'Office' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 1005 "ID", '++44925555800' "PHONE", 'Home' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 1007 "ID", '++44925555111' "PHONE", 'Office' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 1009 "ID", '++44925552341' "PHONE", 'Office' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 1009 "ID", '++44925552344' "PHONE", 'Home' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 1009 "ID", '++44925555865' "PHONE", 'Home 2' "CONTACT_TYPE", 'Some other data' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual 
        )
SELECT
    ID, Count(*) "COUNT_CONTACTS"
FROM
    tbl
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING 
  Count(CASE WHEN CONTACT_TYPE = 'Office' THEN 1 END) > 0 And Count(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
  ID

/* R e s u l t :
            ID COUNT_CONTACTS
    ---------- --------------
          1001              2 
          1009              3
*/
```

WITH clause is here just to generatee some sample data and is not part of the answer.
Use HAVING clause to filter the rows with at least one Office contact and more than 1 total contacts.
Regards..